# Power limit in a 2x1600W server

Tags: electrical-power, power-supply-unit

I have a server with two 1600W power supply units (a Gigabyte GS-R22PHL if that helps).

Should I assume the maximum rated power is 1600W, and that the second unit is for redundancy, or that the combined 3200W are available to the system? I apologize for the somewhat trivial question, but the manual does not mention anything either way, so I assume some standard practice is in play here.

Comment: The basic description alone states `80 PLUS Platinum 1600W redundant PSU` and answers your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum it CAN draw will be 1.6Kw, in reality you won't be able to do that even if you fit the most power-hungry components, in real terms you're unlikely to use 70% of that even if the server is 'pegged' at 100% utilisation of all components 100% of the time.

Most server manufacturers actually list their maximum and average power draws but I noticed that model doesn't list them like that so I'd go with Theoretical_Max=1.6Kw, Realistic_Max=1.12Kw but if you measure it I bet it's mostly pulling about 700-900w almost all the time.

Comment: Thank you. I thought as much, but I guess I was hoping ;-) Realistically, this server is going to use maybe 500W all the time, and only when the coprocessor expansion cards kick in push to 1200-1300W

Comment: Now I'm intrigued - "coprocessor expansion cards" - what's that?

Comment: That's what Intel calls the MIC/Larrabee/Knight's landing. Marketing name is Xeon Phi. I am using the term somewht liberally as these systems will have both PHI and GPU accelerators.

Comment: Oh I know larrabee well, we tested it as an engineering sample years ago, we never really took them into production and moved to nvidia tensor stuff for ML.

Comment: makes sense - but now a Larrabee can be bought for $40, it is interesting hardware to teach parallel programming with MPI on the cheap.

Answer (score 1):

Generally systems with redundant power-supplies are designed for exactly that, redundancy.  When one power-supply fails, is unplugged or whatever, the other  must be sufficient to keep the system running by itself.

That means that the second power-supply is not designed to allow the system to draw more power than a single outlet/power-supply can provide.

Comment: Thank you. I thought as much, but I guess I was hoping ;-) Realistically, this server is going to use maybe 500W all the time, and only when the coprocessor expansion cards kick in push to 1200-1300W